# R wordcloud2 showing blank page

Tags: r, filepath, wordcloud2

I'm trying to make a wordcloud with wordcloud2 from cran page (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html) and I've downloaded it using the commands

```
install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")
```

I've got a dataframe `most_words`:

```
> head(most_words)
  word    n
1  sir 8748
2 time 8100
3 miss 5976
4 hand 5787
5 dear 5486
6 head 5436

> dput(head(most_words))
structure(list(word = c("sir", "time", "miss", "hand", "dear", 
"head"), n = c(8748L, 8100L, 5976L, 5787L, 5486L, 5436L)), .Names = c("word", 
"n"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

and a picture `download.png` on my desktop

when I run the command for wordcloud2 without using the picture I get an answer

```
wordcloud2(head(most_words,100), size = 0.7, shape = 'star')
```

but when I try to put the wordcloud on the picture I just get an empty frame with no error

```
wordcloud2(head(most_words,100), figPath="/Users/username/Desktop/download.png" , size = .2, color = "skyblue")
```

Do you have any idea why this happens? (I suspect the problem is with figpath but i don't get any errors)

Comment: It's broken: https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/12

Comment: The link says it works with refreshing, but it doesn't for me (after many times refreshing). also on different projects by people I work with, it's working fine. I'm just wondering if there's a work around the bug

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading the package:

`library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")`